# Convert a number representing the position of the characters in the dictionary to the original string

Tags: python, string, algorithm

So given a function that maps

`a = 0, b = 1, ..., z = 25`

`25` could either be `cf` or `z`. I need to write a function that given a number returns all the possible "ascii" strings that the number could represent (`cf` and `z` in the example above).

**EDIT**: the string could be any length, not just 2 chars, so that if I pass to the function `1213` it could be either `1-2-1-3` (`bcbd`), or `12-1-3`, or `12-13`, or `1-2-13` and so on.

I can see this can be tackled with recursion but I don't know how to actually keep track of the different values as I go through the string. Any hint on what the algorithm might be?

PS: this is not homework, it is a question they throw at me during a phone screen. Needless to say, it didn't go well :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to recurse.

While you have at least 1 digit, keep recursing. The cases then are:

- no digits: return an empty string, end function
- at least 1 digit: look up character for first digit, add recursive values
- at least 2 digits: look up character for first 2 digits if it exists, and recurse with the rest of the values.

This branching then leads to multiple options, you'll need to loop over those and produce the product of the results. This is easier with a generator approach:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

def find_words(digits):
    if not digits:
        yield ''
        return
    first = letters[int(digits[0])]
    for remainder in find_words(digits[1:]):
        yield first + remainder
    if len(digits) > 1 and int(digits[:2]) < 26:
        firsttwo = letters[int(digits[:2])]
        for remainder in find_words(digits[2:]):
            yield firsttwo + remainder
```

Demo:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
>>> def find_words(digits):
...     if not digits:
...         yield ''
...         return
...     first = letters[int(digits[0])]
...     for remainder in find_words(digits[1:]):
...         yield first + remainder
...     if len(digits) > 1 and int(digits[:2]) < 26:
...         firsttwo = letters[int(digits[:2])]
...         for remainder in find_words(digits[2:]):
...             yield firsttwo + remainder
... 
>>> for word in find_words('1213'):
...     print(word)
... 
bcbd
bcn
bvd
mbd
mn
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps I haven't been clear, but I know how to lookup stuff in a dict ;) The tricky part is that the string could be any length, not just 2 chars, so that if I pass to the function `1213` it could be either `1-2-1-3` (`bcbd`), or `12-1-3`, or `12-13`, or `1-2-13`  and so on -- that's where it gets messy!

Comment: @whatnot123: right, you were indeed not clear; that's another thing a phone screen looks for; if you can communicate such constraints clearly. :-P

Comment: Lol well I never said the string was limited to 2 chars though - you assumed that from my example... but it would have been a joke of a phone screen if that was the case :) Anyway I edited the original question...

Comment: @whatnot123: that took me longer than I'd like to admit; it is well past my bedtime, is all I can say.

Comment: why to repeat the function definition that you just gave two lines above? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters that question gave me a bit of a headache and wasn't easy at all, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we can define your mapping function as a list lookup in `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
>>> import string
>>> f = lambda i: string.ascii_lowercase[i]
>>> f(0)
'a'
>>> f(25)
'z'
```

This function does the integer partitioning:

```
>>> def part_int(s, max_i=len(string.ascii_lowercase)):
...     if s:
...         for j in range(1, len(s)+1):
...             i = int(s[:j])
...             if i >= max_i: break
...             for p in part_int(s[j:], max_i):
...                 yield [i] + p
...     else:
...         yield []
...
>>> list(part_int('1258'))
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 25, 8], [12, 5, 8]]
```

You can use `map()` to map your function to these numbers:

```
>>> def int2str(i):
...     return map(lambda l: ''.join(map(f, l)), part_int(str(i)))
...
>>> list(int2str(25))
['cf', 'z']
>>> list(int2str(1258))
['bcfi', 'bzi', 'mfi']
```

Comment: I guess the recurrence relation is: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)` in the worst case, hence it is `O(2^n)`. Am I correct?

Comment: if `n` is the length of the string, and there was no `if i >= max_i: break` yes, but that line greatly cuts off the search tree